# Using JSON to update app's content in iOS

Tags: objective-c, ios, json

I'm about to create an application that uses JSON to update its content.
This is how I planned it to work:
When application starts, it checks (with internet connection is available) if the JSON file set on remote server is newer than the one stored localy - if it is then it's downloaded. 
Then, the application applies data from that JSON to the content. For example, to the "Contact" information - it applies data like phone numbers etc.

My question is, is it in your opinion, a good technique to update appliactions content?
Does anynone had an experience with building app with this kind of idea?

Best regards,
Zin

Answer (score 0):

Of course you can do this. One thing that may lead to a better user experience would be to ask the user for his permission to download new content (if there is something new).

Comment: I figured out that the JSON shouldn't be bigger then 3-5kb. So I hope to pass it unnoticed (but there is an idea of indicating that something is being downloaded as well as the option to turn it off).

Comment: Well - should be ok. But the user should be somehow informed that a (and which) contact has been updated.

Answer (score 0):

This is a normal thing to do.  I have a phonebook app that does exactly this.  On a side note, if you need a network class to handle the web-service interaction, see [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10618056/how-to-post-more-parameters-with-image-upload-code-in-ios/10618557#10618557).  I wrote a custom network class that works with [AFNetworking](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking/).

Comment: Nice, thanks for the reply. I'll the other post on go on with my work.