# MVC Design in iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, model-view-controller

I am creating an iPhone app that allows you to specify certain criteria, fetches a list of events from a web service, and lists the events in a table view so that users can add the individual event to their calendar.

How should I approach this with the MVC pattern?  Will be using JSON.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

If you are going to be consuming JSON based web-services, you might want to check out AFNetworking.  I wrote a network class to work with AFN, check out [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10618056/how-to-post-more-parameters-with-image-upload-code-in-ios/10618557#10618557) for the code.

Answer (score 0):

User calendar and the list of events and how you fetch them is the model. Table view is the view. Classes that glue the two together are the controller. Doesn't matter if you use JSON or whatever else if we are talking about general architecture here.