# post an object that contains data from iOS to PHP

Tags: php, ios, ios5, post

I'd like to pass an object such as this (JavaScript example)

```
var auth = new Object();
auth.method = "authenticateUser";
auth.data = new Object();
auth.data.email = "user11111@test.com";
auth.data.password = "123123";
```

to a php script when I'm making a post.

So far, I can only pass individual variables by appending to the url, but I'd like to be able to pass nested objects - such as in javascript examples above

```
NSString *post =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"username=%@&password=%@",usernameField.text, passwordField.text];
NSString *hostStr = @"{ANY URL}";
hostStr = [hostStr stringByAppendingString:post];
NSData *dataURL =  [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL: [ NSURL URLWithString: hostStr ]];    
NSString *serverOutput = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:dataURL encoding: NSASCIIStringEncoding];
```

Answer (score 0):

Right now, you're using HTTP GET, which is hard to transmit complex data. What you can do is [send an HTTP Post in iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5537297/ios-how-to-perform-a-http-post-request) which uses the url and attaches the data inside a message body.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked into [AFNetworking](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking)?  This makes it much easier to do what you are wanting.  Almost every project I do involves a web-service of some kind, and a library like AFNetworking makes this process much easier.  For one thing, you never want to pass a password along in a GET request, and you also want to make sure you are using a secure connection when passing credentials or sensitive data like that.

I have written a network class designed to work with AFNetworking.  [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10618056/how-to-post-more-parameters-with-image-upload-code-in-ios/10618557#10618557) is an SO post that details the class.