# Best way of working with core-data and webservices

Tags: objective-c, web-services, core-data

I'm very new to IOS Development. Now for my first project I need to build an app that retrieves data from a webService.

Now I also want to use core data. Do you people know the best practise way of doing this ? Any good tutorials?

Kind regards!

Comment: RestKit is an excellent framework for mapping your remote resources to local Coredata-backed models. You can [find the project here](https://github.com/RestKit/RestKit). Also there are plenty of tutorials and examples out there, so a Google search would be enough to get you started.

Answer (score 0):

Try this tut from ray. It has two parts. It should give you a good understanding of how to parse data from web with core data. Hope it helps. Adrian.
Here is the link: http://www.raywenderlich.com/17927/how-to-synchronize-core-data-with-a-web-service-part-2

Answer (score 0):

u can try **[RestKit](http://restkit.org/)**

> RestKit is an Objective-C framework for iOS that aims to make
>   interacting with RESTful web services simple, fast and fun. It
>   combines a clean, simple HTTP request/response API with a powerful
>   object mapping system that reduces the amount of code you need to
>   write to get stuff done.
>
> Building on top of the object mapping layer, RestKit provides
>   integration with Apple’s Core Data framework. This support allows
>   RestKit to persist remotely loaded objects directly back into a local
>   store, either as a fast local cache or a primary data store that is
>   periodically synced with the cloud. RestKit can populate Core Data
>   associations for you, allowing natural property based traversal of
>   your data model. It also provides a nice API on top of the Core Data
>   primitives that simplifies configuration and querying use cases.

Answer (score 0):

AFNetworking is a great way to consume web services.  I wrote a [semi] complete class that makes it fairly easy to call POST based web-services.  See [THIS SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10618056/how-to-post-more-parameters-with-image-upload-code-in-ios/10618557#10618557) for more details and the class itself.