# Cannot use AFNetworking to upload image

Tags: afnetworking, rubymotion

I am creating an iOS app using Rubymotion. I am trying to make a multipart upload
of an image.

*I use this code to make upload but I get error:*

```
data = {token: "2xCGdzcuEeNzhst3Yaa8f", task: 1, message: "message", latitude: 1, longitude: 1}

    client = AFHTTPClient.alloc.initWithBaseURL(NSURL.URLWithString("http://api.example.com/api/v1/"))

        request = client.multipartFormRequestWithMethod('POST', path:"messages", parameters:data, constructingBodyWithBlock:lambda{ |form_data|
          image_data = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image.image)
          form_data.appendPartWithFileData(image_data, name:'new_avatar', fileName:'new_avatar.png', mimeType:'image/png')
        })

        operation = AFJSONRequestOperation.alloc.initWithRequest(request)
        operation.setCompletionBlockWithSuccess(lambda{ |operation, responseObject| puts 'all done!'})
```

*I get this error:*

```
undefined method `setCompletionBlockWithSuccess' for #<AFJSONRequestOperation:0xb227f00> (NoMethodError)
```

From what I can see, operation is a valid object and should have this method.
Am I missing something here?

**Update 1**

This is my updated code but when I run it the POST action does not seem to fire. Am I still missing any code? I do not get any errors either.

```
data = {token: "2xCGdzcuEeNzhs5tYaa8f", task: 1, message: "message", latitude: 1, longitude: 1}

    client = AFHTTPClient.alloc.initWithBaseURL(NSURL.URLWithString("http://api.example.com/api/v1/"))

    request = client.multipartFormRequestWithMethod('POST', path:"messages", parameters:data, constructingBodyWithBlock:lambda{ |form_data|
      image_data = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image.image)
      form_data.appendPartWithFileData(image_data, name:'new_avatar', fileName:'new_avatar.png', mimeType:'image/png')
    })

    operation = AFJSONRequestOperation.alloc.initWithRequest(request)
    operation.setCompletionBlockWithSuccess(lambda { |operation, responseObject| puts 'all done!'},
                                            failure: lambda { |operation, error| puts 'error' })
```

*The request object outputs this:*

```
<NSMutableURLRequest:195641792 - url: http://api.example.com/api/v1/messages, 
    headers: {"Content-Length"=>"118200", "Content-Type"=>"multipart/form-data; boundary=Boundary+0xAbCdEfGbOuNdArY", "Accept-Language"=>"en, fr, de, ja, nl, it, es, pt, pt-PT, da, fi, nb, sv, ko, zh-Hans, zh-Hant, ru, pl, tr, uk, ar, hr, cs, el, he, ro, sk, th, id, ms, en-GB, ca, hu, vi, en-us;q=0.8", "User-Agent"=>"theapp/1.0 (iPhone Simulator; iOS 6.0; Scale/1.00)"}, 
    cache policy: 0, Pipelining: false, main doc url: ,    timeout: 60.0, network service type: 0 >
```

*The operation object outputs this:*

```
<AFJSONRequestOperation:0xa78c660>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method signature is `setCompletionBlockWithSuccess(lambda..., failure: lambda...)` -- you need to add a failure parameter. Something like this:

```
operation.setCompletionBlockWithSuccess(lambda { |operation, responseObject| puts 'all done!'},
                                        failure: lambda { |operation, error| puts 'error' })
```

Also, you'll want to make sure to actually start the request operation:

```
operation.start
```

See https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking/blob/master/AFNetworking/AFJSONRequestOperation.m#L102-L103 for the definition of this method.

Comment: Thanks! I got rid of the error message now but the POST action does not seem to fire. Please see my updated question.

Comment: Did you actually start the request? `operation.start`

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a class to do this kind of work.  Check out my answer [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10618056/how-to-post-more-parameters-with-image-upload-code-in-ios).  It uses AFNetworking and includes methods for basic network requests.

Comment: Thanks, but unfortunately I am using Rubymotion (Ruby) and not objective-c. Any idea why I get this error?

Comment: You can install CocoaPods (motion-cocoapod) and include AFNetworking in your RubyMotion app using `pod "AFNetworking"` in your Rakefile. More about CocoaPods here: https://github.com/HipByte/motion-cocoapods.

Comment: Yes, I am using that pod together with the AFmotion gem. Found no way upload images with that gem directly so I am trying raw AF code.