# Asynchronous Asihttprequest

Tags: ios, iphone, asynchronous, asihttprequest

i want to show data asynchronously, it work successfuly and i get response quickly in my log message but it takes too much time to hide spinner, and also i am unable to show data into my tableview quickly, can i know what is reason for it?

```
-(void) clubsDetail:(int)catID
{

    NSString *link = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",KWSURLVenu];
    NSLog(@"%@",link);

    ASIFormDataRequest *request = [ASIFormDataRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:link]];
    [request setRequestMethod:@"POST"];

    [request setPostValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",  catID] forKey:@"cat_id"];
    NSLog(@"%d",catID);
    [request setCompletionBlock:^{
        NSString *jsonString = [request responseString];
        NSLog(@"response %@",jsonString);
        NSArray *dataArray = (NSArray *) [jsonString JSONValue];
        NSDictionary * returnDicto = nil;
        NSLog(@"response after parsin");
//        NSDictionary * returnDict = [returnDicto objectForKey:@"club_info"] ;

        [slideDetail_dataArray removeAllObjects];
//        if ([returnDict objectForKey:@"club_info"]) {


        for(returnDicto in dataArray)
        {
            PostClubDC *postDC = [[PostClubDC alloc] init];
            NSDictionary * returnDict = [returnDicto objectForKey:@"club_info"] ;
            postDC.postID = [[returnDict objectForKey:@"Id"]integerValue];
            postDC.postCatID = [[returnDict objectForKey:@"cat_id"]integerValue];
            postDC.postName = [returnDict objectForKey:@"name"];
            postDC.postHeadLine = [returnDict objectForKey:@"headline"];
            postDC.postImage = [returnDict objectForKey:@"image"];
            postDC.postLat = [returnDict objectForKey:@"long"];
            postDC.postAddress = [returnDict objectForKey:@"address"];
            postDC.postSummary = [returnDict objectForKey:@"summary"];
            postDC.postStat = [returnDict objectForKey:@"stat"];
            postDC.postUS = [returnDict objectForKey:@"us"];
            NSDictionary * returnDictic = [returnDicto objectForKey:@"club_rating"];
            postDC.postGoodRate = [returnDictic objectForKey:@"good"];
            postDC.postGreatRate = [returnDictic objectForKey:@"great"];
            [slideDetail_dataArray addObject:postDC];
        }

        // hide spinner
        [[myActivityIndicator currentIndicator]hide];
        [tbl_slideDetail reloadData];
    }];
//    [request setFailedBlock:^{
//        NSError *error = [request error];
//    }];
    [request startAsynchronous];
    // show spinner

    [[myActivityIndicator currentIndicator] displayActivity:@"Loading"];
}
```

Comment: PLease be aware that ASIHtppRequest is no longer maintained and has some known bugs.

Comment: please tell me what should i do?

Comment: I seems for loop is taking a long time to complete iteration. Check 'dataArray' count it must a large number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your problem is that you are trying to change the UI from a thread other than the main. Try changing this code to see if this helps:

```
    // hide spinner
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        // hide spinner on main thread
        [[myActivityIndicator currentIndicator]hide];
        [tbl_slideDetail reloadData];
    });
```

Comment: Well, when you make an async request the response executes on a separate thread (completionBlock). You cannot change anything UI related from a thread other than the main. So what we do is tell the app to run this piece of code on the main thread. This is done by using `dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{ ... });`.

Answer (score 0):

Since you asked what you should do in the comments, switch to [AFNetworking 2.0](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking).  AFN uses blocks instead of delegate methods, and once you get used to how it works, it is much easier to work with than ASI.

[Here is a link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10618056/how-to-post-more-parameters-with-image-upload-code-in-ios/10618557#10618557) to a (very) old [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10618056/how-to-post-more-parameters-with-image-upload-code-in-ios/10618557#10618557) that has an example of how to work with AFN (this has changed slightly for version 2.0).  Lots of updated examples online ([Ray Wenderlich](http://www.raywenderlich.com/59255/afnetworking-2-0-tutorial))

Comment: That is the current version.  There was a major change from 1.? to 2.0.  Minor changes since then.